# Does clicking an Amazon S3 Object's URL count as GET request?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, get-request

i just started my AWS account today.AWS Free Tier provides restricted S3 usage and  allows me to make 20.000 GET requests per month. I plan to upload an image to the S3 Bucket, then copy the given URL of the uploaded image, and finally store the URL in MongoDB. My question is: does clicking the S3 Bucket's URL count as a GET request? And does using the S3 Bucket's URL as a parameter for an img tag also count as a GET request?

I previously asked this question to AI, and it said yes, it counts as a GET request. However, I wanted to confirm this to be sure.

Comment: Yes, each would count as a GET request for that object. (Assuming your browser doesn't already have the image cached.)

Comment: It sounds like you are making these S3 objects public so just be aware that anyone with the URL can download them (and each of those downloads would count as a GET obviously).

Comment: @jarmod yes, i know.Thanks for warning.